# Как правильно прописывать script в footer или сообщениях об ошибках в console?

Tags: php, html, require

Сделал что-то вроде шаблона для всех страниц header.php, footer.php и вставил их в index.php, в settings.php и другие (require('footer.php')). Но когда переключаюсь между страницами, в консоли появляются сообщения об ошибках. То элемент не найден, то атрибут элемента и т.д. Но оно и понятно: элемент, который есть в index.php, может отсутствовать на других страницах (и наоборот). Получается, footer.php сделал, чтоб он был на всех страницах. Но как быть со `<script>`, который прописан в footer.php? Покажите как правильно? Спасибо за помощь!

Как выглядит 'footer.php':

```
    <footer class="footer">
    </footer>
  </div><!--wrapper-->
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo '<script>';

Comment: Нее, вы не поняли) Например, в script.js есть строка document.querySelector('#some'), этот элемент есть в index.php, но в нет в settings.php. Поэтому js ругается, то элемент не найден и т.п

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас не нейден элемент страницы, то значит его там нет.

Это может произойти из-за:

1. Вы его не вывели
2. Страницы не загрузилась полность в момент выполнения

Решения:

1. Делать проверку, что элемент найден
2. Запускать скрипт после загрузки страницы
3. Подключать скрипт только на тех страницах, на которых он действительно нужен

---

Скрипт подключается через тег

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
```

---

Многие полезные и удобные вещи уже реализованы, например, в [jQuery](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?bu=hnar&from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=2573.dWtQKmAr2WlBQ-rTz0GnHKmOl6-L4At20r8hHxMwfuk.e35ed78a61647cf03879b9e9f0608dd9fa13d00f&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9T6U0-imFY5IWwl6BSUGTYl260BtXWEO1fYBbfuDJfoS6owEBu71EkHE5O1l0JSEZjBZgadFp3wx493kDG9DXP_joaNkfPnA39YUaFomwubYvX20jkyzFqa5XNIy7HRsDEDkNpijKwu6MXo38GYyfg8dmuEoPejiBw,,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszk9yzKd9YIesTd3a7Jh6kfSvj81arGvoiFXpYh6yPvz371LUh3WSgUo25LtznAtvZBTHaZk08Crih8fxcMxklWgDpy58Sgqb_mrAqTJWnD_3YgKjqC39hQPU6wK7zmw4_gJFdGbnuUUCPh2eeP-eVUHZonUmtWSS54uK2G3yxqVwWWTCffQo8EtytW3234U6xIUs-UiDgV9KJ7ylCqn7_hrTlTlhHC7aLBb_-zGlq2hINCBt7fsIJF6r0d4kdSp4fXt15ztwWBRFV-RXdn7bLG_4msEr-O2cQK5aBP3T5b1nqYkLj3cDlnwfxTDg-3GDwAOiS7wBgX3oxz0d1vB00yBFPFaGvPG2zQXIb4Gdz8Yxre1SorRxiKbPOib4KWwMsT8tkz67i9YHMrqBmYGDu9SgBvU4CTXFzS2RF05CsWkYMmHjOINS-s-k7UOCmD5GO___Q_VtDviq9lEK6bZ4NOtTGyR3thCC0nJtvAE9NOWWGzvGa2OB7w3DcS6npNT4RnCLt6Fq8mRY1Em8I0NyTBAQzq9P0xpUlgp2MNYBDyu32zkiteRqh8WuHt4C9E0z8iI2vyhQoYT0AwfRHGT_38CLmzlbHvsGnW7VBYbrFFPul3T4CgIjuXRUXeUoW01kwJ-h_eooJl2Euyv6JkPomssu-YexQzVgftlNZdMJ9acPqWjQeKo0doEDfc5mGn0uyvweP11VHUytU_A96XgS0E5JVcQhnK7fgYyi9D3hCaWXFtCd2X0KBZu0Rk3wMNx9B9PIvSSov2tdXvqmQ5zaEkNp9-1e3j4n_m4xSUe3Jj6KnMQ44JKJYrCQSNg1mMhX2C2-YU0NvtpPacP8iONdl9cQz5Yr_Q85wBD3V46Xe3CS_VH1plOn7zrCo2ryoudHqkCI1l1N4G_xYOfXBkuxamRXn91HEzUz4FYK5qGw00SeADWelqFD_E4wykL5Tc65FIlV6a-1-0vbf_RkH7cqJvnw2pxPkF9Md3cw8pfwD-wn894zkya35Ect5qPF23RTkncbJsatCxMc5YwBCbOHY93UL4xK6UQMsEg,,&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXRFdYR3lUTjgydlcwejJSOG9sQ0JldGVjcWlna2tTclJXS21pb1VieWFodXBZVzFDSTBMYTZvb3N2Y1RKNlpjUERoV2hqQTlnSzRn&sign=865a36ec84e0f0b350ce0146e0af337e&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpfmwSlf_6ZUYZ2BPbpFQPbguCA7uJG_aNVB1T9jz3a1WAd78j16JdJQ,,&l10n=ru&rp=1&cts=1562928199828&mc=1&hdtime=1786).

Comment: "Подключать скрипт только на тех страницах..." Как сделать проверку, что n-странице будет n-скрипт, а на m будет, соответственно, m? При этом прописывать script в footer.php?

Comment: Если на чистом php, то `<?php if (page_url == ...) { : ?><script...><?php elif ... ?>`

Comment: Ну или в header указать переменную-массив для хранения путей подключаемых скриптов, в включаемых файлах запихивать в нее пути на скрипты, а в футоере выводить